# Selecting by data-attr (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select a div by `data-attr` and then show or hide it.

For example: `$('div.product-details')` where attr is 1 toggle `.show()` / `.hide()`.

Can anyone show me how to do this? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### JavaScript:

You can use [`document.querySelector(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to do this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaeu240p/)

```
var elem = document.querySelector('div[data-name="alex"]');
elem.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.opacity = '0';
}
elem.onmouseleave = function() {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

#### jQuery:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaeu240p/1/)

```
$('[data-name="alex"]').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css({'opacity': '0'});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({'opacity': '1'});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute value selector to get element by their attribute value:

```
var divObj = $('div.product-details[data-attr="1"]');
```